# java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: connect timed out, iss: <>@<>.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, google-cloud-pubsub

i get this error after i change from local to docker-compose environmente,
I deploy my containers with the same localtime and zone as my host using volumes:

```
volumes:
  - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
  - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
```

I verify it is ok and don't know why there is a connection time out error.
what can be the error ? because it works fine when i run it on intellij and then it crashes in docker-compose deployment.

This is where i get the error:

```
this.credentials =
                GoogleCredentials
                    .fromStream(is)
                    .createScoped(Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/rcsbusinessmessaging"));
            this.credentials.refreshIfExpired();
```

Seems like a network issue but my firewall is down and i dont really know if it is allowing traffic from my container to the google's tokens endpoint.
Variables "is" is an InputStream with my google credentials

Also I have a connection to pubsub as well

```
GoogleCredentials credentials =
                GoogleCredentials.fromStream(is2)
                    .createScoped(
                        Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub"));
            credentials.refreshIfExpired();
```

Where "is2" is another inputstream with my service account key.

Comment: Please include a minimally reproducible example in questions. It's difficult to determine the problem from an error message. Is your error message obfuscated? Or did the error literally include `<>@<>.iam.gserviceaccount.com`? I suspect (!?) that you're not mounting the Service Account key into the container when you containerize the solution

Comment: I put the service account key in a vault container which my container it's reading it from, in local environmente I use the vault container in another docker-compose file to run it and it connects well, now doing it in the same docker compose file is reading and i can crud vault keys and so on, but the connection to gcp is the connection time out error

Comment: and yes it is obfuscated, the <> are for an example

Comment: OK, so it sounds as though there's a networking issue between the container and Google's token endpoint. It's difficult to diagnose mostly blind to your solution. Code, logs etc. would help.

Comment: it seems like a network error but how can I allow my container to do the request to google's token endpoint? and in my local machine where it is deployed is running fine within intellij

Comment: @DazWilkin i did some updates on information if it may help :(

Comment: Logs would be helpful for the code that you included above. I don't code in Java and so can't quickly attempt to repro your issue. If the host can access Google's services, then it's unlikely that Docker Compose (if running on the same machine) would have issues (but it's possible). I think it's more likely that you're not providing the key correctly to the container. Using a stream to do this is unconventional but I assume because of Vault.

Comment: im sure credentials are been send just fine, here is where it stops and timed out:
curl -v --compressed -X POST -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -H 'User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.41.7 (gzip)' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -d '@-' -- 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' << $$$

Answer (score 0):

It was a network issue solved it in the yml file:
network_mode: "bridge"
or
network_mode: "host"